Partitioning a sequence of real numbers to a finite number of convergent subsequences
By the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem we know that a bounded infinite sequence of real numbers has a convergent subsequence. What I'm wondering about is whether we can do more.
Here's my idea, which I'm not sure is correct: By applying Bolzano–Weierstrass again to the elements not participating in the convergent subsequence, we can get another convergent subsequence, and so on. We can always add to the new subsequence the first element of the original sequence not yet chosen for any subsequence, so this process generates a partition of the original sequence to an infinite number of convergent subsequences.
My question: can we partition a sequence into a finite number of convergent subsequences? My guess is no, but I couldn't find a counterexample.

A counterexample is given by any sequence having an interval of limit points. Like ${ \sin n \mid n \in \mathbb N}$. See also this post.

By B-W, a bounded sequence of real numbers always has at least one limit point. Such a sequence could have a finite number of limit points (for example, it has one limit point), in which case, yes we can partition the sequence into a finite number of convergent sub-sequences. However, it is instead possible that such a sequence has an infinite number of limit points, in which case no, we cannot partition the sequence into finitely many convergent subsequences.

By B-W, a bounded sequence of real numbers always has at least one limit point. Such a sequence (i.e. a bounded sequence of real numbers) could have a finite number of limit points (for example, it has one limit point), in which case, yes we can partition the sequence into a finite number of convergent sub-sequences. However, it is instead possible that such a sequence (i.e. a bounded sequence of real numbers) has an infinite number of limit points, in which case no, we cannot partition the sequence into finitely many convergent sub-sequences.
